# Is there an example of a category which is cocartesian coclosed (or co-(cartesian closed))?

Tags: category-theory

One obvious example is a co-Heyting algebra such as the closed sets of a topological space. But what about other examples ?

Answer (score 2):

Either I'm misunderstanding the question, or the dual of any cartesian closed category is an example (and these are all the examples). So, for example, the dual of the category of sets will do, as will the dual of any other topos.

Comment: This is obvious, but I was looking for a "positive" example. For instance, if someone was asking for an example of a co-Heyting algebra, I wouldn't answer "the dual of any Heyting algebra", but "the lattice of closed sets of a topological space" for example. I'd like as an example a co-(cartesian closed) category $C$ where a morphism $A\rightarrow B$ is a "genuine" morphism that can be described without going back to it's dual in $C^{op}$.

Comment: @Sephi OK, how about the category of complete, atomic Boolean algebras and complete homomorphisms? That seems to satisfy your requirements of "genuine morphisms", but it's equivalent to the dual of the category of sets. I suspect that, because of the equivalence, you won't like this example, but then you should give a clear explanation of what you mean by "positive example" and "genuine morphism" and "can be described without going back".

Comment: Thank you for your example ! I wasn't aware of that equivalence, which is nice and certainly not a problem (why would it be ?). And since the objects of $\text{Sets}^{op}$ are positively described as complete atomic boolean algebras, it's possible to work with arrows in $\text{Sets}^{op}$ without seeing them as (reversed) arrows in $\text{Sets}$. This is what I was looking for.